# How can I fix it this error raspberry pi3b+

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I try this command on raspberry pi 3b+ google-oauthlib-tool --client-secrets ~/googleassistant/credentials.json \ --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype \ --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gcm \ --save --headless and I have this error: missing option "--scope"

I use this tutorial: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-google-assistant/

Answer (score 0):

you have to paste the url and press enter and wait for a while until you get the complete url on your command line, and then you can copy that and paste search to get your google assistant accesss.